# Avoid duplicates in database using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have the following data in C# which is written to a sql database:

```
public class Office
{
    [Key]
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Circuit")]
    public virtual int CircuitId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CircuitId")]
    public virtual Circuit Circuits { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "OfficeContact")]
    public virtual int OfficeContactId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OfficeContactId")]
    public virtual OfficeContact OfficeContacts { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RegionalTechnician")]
    public virtual int RegionalTechnicianId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RegionalTechnicianId")]
    public virtual RegionalTechnician RegionalTechnicians { get; set; }
}

public class OfficeContact
{
    [Key]
    public int OfficeContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Currently a new Office record is written for every OfficeContact even if the Office already exists. I would like to have only one Office record per office address but allow multiple OfficeContact records as long as the OfficeContacts are diffrent.

Also how do you select all the office contacts for a given office.

Guessing you could check to make sure that the Office does not exists before saving to the database but then how do you associate the OfficeContact with an existing Office.

This is how the data is saved:

```
Office office = new Office()
{
    Address = cbAddress.Text,
    City = cbCity.Text,
};

context.Offices.Add(office);
context.SaveChanges();

OfficeContact officeContact = new OfficeContact()
{
    Name = cbLocalOfficeContactName.Text,
    Email = tbLocalOfficeEmail.Text,
    Phone = tbLocalOfficePhone.Text
};

context.OfficeContacts.Add(officeContact);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This seems more like a "read the documentation" task to me. You're asking how to do something that is probably on page 1 of the documentation.

Comment: It should be simple if I understand correctly. You just need to query the table for existing office corresponding to current address, if it is null then create a new office object and save else take the office id of the existing object and assign it to the contract object 's office id property and save.

Comment: Thanks Priyank, I believe you have answered my question.